# shell script - how to use variables for a shell script without defining the variable in the script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Raspbian (Jessy) - root@Raspberry Pi - Putty

In the Terminal i type in

```
finalanswer=0
```

now i got a script with this code

```
#!/bin/bash
source /lib/lsb/init-functions

echo $finalanswer              #just as a test
if [ ! "$finalanswer" = "0" ]
then
        rm -r mnt/objects/all
        log_warning_msg "All Files has been deleted" || true
        touch its_over.txt
else
        let finalanswer=1
        log_action_msg "Var finalanswer was 0. setting back to 1" || true
fi
```

there is a cronjob that starts this script every hour

sooo. somewhere there must be an error. 
because he is reading the Variable $finalanswer as nothing.

that means variables that has been defined outside of this script will not work?

how do i fix this?

Comment: The variable you're setting is `finalquestion`, but your script uses `$finalanswer`. Which is it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Shell variables are not inherited by child processes. If you want a variable to be inherited, it has to be an environment variable. You create environment variables using the `export` command.

```
export finalanswer=0
```

or

```
finalanswer=0
export finalanswer
```

You can also export a variable just for the duration of a command by putting the assignment at the beginning of the command:

```
finalanswer=0 /path/to/script
```

Note that variables you assign in your shell will **not** be accessible to `cron` jobs. Variables can only be exported to processes that are descended from the shell, and processes run by `cron` are not related to your shell process. If you want to set a variable for use in a `cron` job, you can put the assignment into the crontab file itself.

Comment: Thanks that worked. But the script is now unable to change it again to 1. Do i have to write "export" instead of "let" in the script to reach the 1?

Comment: @AmirBoudani, a script can't change its parent process's variable values at all. Propagation is only from parent to child, not child to parent.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy so there is no solution to use a variable that has been signed outside of the script and change it inside of the script?

Comment: You can use `source scriptname` to run the script in the same shell, so its variable assignments will persist.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35586479/set-variables-in-bash-script for how to set variables in a shell script and use them outside the script.

Comment: @AmirBoudani, you absolutely can change a variable inside a script, but if you want that change to be visible **to a process that isn't either the interpreter running the script or a child of same**, then here aren't any options available that don't involve the interpreter that needs to receive the variable being explicitly written to go out of its way to do so (ie. reading it from the script's stdout). `source` makes the interpreter running the script be the same one that started it, which is why it works.

Answer (score 1):

You can define a variable for a single command by placing its definition before the command you wish to run:

```
$ VARIABLE=hunter perl -E 'say $ENV{VARIABLE}'
hunter
```

you can do the same thing for a cron entry:

```
*/10 * * * * VARIABLE=hunter <command>
```

Comment: Great answer. But you forgot to mention that exporting the variable will also work.

Comment: @alvits, but for cron, where do you declare the exported variable? This answer is very explicit about that.

Comment: @glennjackman - if the answer is only specific to cron, then I'd agree there's no need to mention it. But the OP specifically gave an example running the script manually and this answer also included the manual execution of a script, I would think it should be mentioned.

Comment: @alvits That's what the first example is.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen - please disregard my comment. [Barmar's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35586093/shell-script-how-to-use-variables-for-a-shell-script-without-defining-the-vari/35586406#35586406)  is more comprehensive and already covered it.