# Set variables in bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command-line, echo

test.sh contains:

```
A=$1
B=$2
```

I set test.sh to chmod 777

I started the script with 2 parameters:

```
./test.sh first last
```

Then I tested it by typing:

```
echo "FirstVar: $A SecondVar: $B"
```

Result:

```
"FirstVar:  SecondVar: "
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: You didn't do anything wrong. Your code worked just like it was supposed to (setting variables valid *in the scope of the interpreter running it*).

Comment: Whatever you are trying to accomplish, making your executables writable by everyone with access to the system is a **serious security problem.** Maybe try `chmod 755` instead.

Answer (score 2):

When you run your script like this:

```
./test.sh whatever
```

Bash runs another instance of shell which interprets command in your script. If you want to set variables in the current shell, you should use `source` command, or dot (`.`). In this case the commands in the script will be executed in the current shell directly.

```
source test.sh
```

or just

```
. test.sh
```